# Scores of action recognition models: how to obain verbs and nouns scores? Can I use margin probabilities?

Tags: python

So I'm using Omnivore model (https://github.com/facebookresearch/omnivore/tree/main/omnivision), and my output is an array of scores for every action. Every action is a verb + noun. There's 3,806 actions. What I need is an array of verb scores and an array for noun scores. I was using margin probability:

```
verb_scores_dict = {}
noun_scores_dict = {}

for pred, score in pred_class_names_all:
    verb, noun = pred.split()

if verb in verb_scores_dict:
  verb_scores_dict[verb] += score
else:
  verb_scores_dict[verb] = score

if noun in noun_scores_dict:
  noun_scores_dict[noun] += score
else:
  noun_scores_dict[noun] = score
      
result_dict={}
result_dict['verb_output'] = []
result_dict['noun_output'] = []
result_dict['narration_id'] = narration_id

# Print the verb and noun scores dictionaries
for verb, scores in verb_scores_dict.items():
    print(f"Verb: {verb}, Verb Scores: {scores}")
    result_dict['verb_output'].append(scores.tolist())
    

for noun, scores in noun_scores_dict.items():
    print(f"Noun: {noun}, Noun Scores: {scores}")
    result_dict['noun_output'].append(scores.tolist())
```

But the thing is that I should get something similar to this:

```
{'verb_output': array([[ 7.72634077,  7.24404097,  0.4986968 , ..., -4.73686218,
        -4.68037271, -4.78593493],
       [10.65037537,  6.22874689,  2.58304691, ..., -4.34611273,
        -4.10662127, -3.87795758],
       [ 4.48676252,  8.9562788 ,  4.78455114, ..., -4.37370729,
        -5.02590704, -3.35811305],
       ...,
       [ 6.71048832,  8.05608559,  5.31442881, ..., -4.34917974,
        -5.15016031, -4.63199329],
       [ 7.93692255,  6.86483002,  3.15329337, ..., -3.71181631,
        -4.52799511, -4.36749268],
       [ 8.39965153,  9.5401535 , 15.13584709, ..., -6.13945246,
        -5.81251431, -3.81169009]]), 'noun_output': array([[-6.6729846 , -2.1299243 ,  1.14122081, ..., -4.76375723,
        -3.65956378, -4.85687351],
       [-0.07463244,  3.85092378,  6.30206203, ..., -4.32961893,
        -3.71707988, -3.77974272],
       [ 3.05986619,  1.97096956,  2.50316858, ..., -4.64014769,
        -3.84915638, -3.59207392],
       ...,
       [ 4.28227949,  3.72166443,  7.30290747, ..., -5.12706661,
        -4.40550518, -3.26095915],
       [ 3.11553764,  7.43528414,  5.56893921, ..., -4.48091173,
        -4.32157898, -2.97596955],
       [ 6.16293764,  3.73808503,  6.44398689, ..., -6.22030973,
        -4.37711859, -5.48904181]]), 'narration_id': array(['P01_101_0', 'P01_101_1', 'P01_101_10', ..., 'P33_105_658',
       'P33_105_659', 'P33_105_66'], dtype='<U11')}
```

And I'm getting something like this:

```
{'verb_output': array([[ -43.78885651, -139.56182861, -110.56599426, ...,  -12.32396984,
          -8.73503685,  -15.43686867],
       [ -42.33675766, -108.72449493, -187.36923218, ...,  -12.29256916,
          -9.07168865,  -15.52522469],
       [ -51.75484848, -119.52777863,  -63.90496063, ...,  -10.2333765 ,
         -14.77134037,   -2.52343321],
       ...,
       [-493.74246216, -503.70645142, -207.50227356, ...,   -5.77831984,
         -22.88568878,   -7.9034214 ],
       [-237.2469635 , -579.89691162, -491.43731689, ...,  -16.16319847,
          -7.59590626,   -8.50958157],
       [-172.81614685, -318.99887085, -426.69381714, ...,   -5.8961854 ,
         -16.30410767,   -8.4819355 ]]), 'noun_output': array([[ -43.78885651, -139.56182861,  -14.37578964, ...,   -2.71890616,
          -2.72560787,  -15.99341011],
       [ -42.33675766, -187.36923218,  -33.00939178, ...,   -5.39493179,
         -15.75678635,   -2.62935948],
       [ -51.75484848, -266.3885498 , -440.42184448, ...,  -15.25948334,
          -5.51948929,   -3.1326921 ],
       ...,
       [-493.74246216, -503.70645142, -207.50227356, ...,   -7.68950129,
          -3.64070535,   -7.95105267],
       [-237.2469635 , -579.89691162, -491.43731689, ...,   -4.07324791,
          -8.35855579,   -4.86216784],
       [-172.81614685, -318.99887085, -426.69381714, ...,   -7.36990547,
          -7.62912035,   -3.9157083 ]]), 'narration_id': array(['P01_11_100', 'P01_11_101', 'P01_11_102', ..., 'P28_26_0',
       'P28_26_10', 'P28_26_1'], dtype='<U10')}
```

As you can see, the values are way higer and negative than the other ones. Has somebody faced something like this? Maybe I have to normalize? Or maybe I can not assume that I can obtain the scores like this? I'm using margin probabilities because I saw it in the official paper, but maybe it doesn't apply to scores. This it what it says:

> Our model is trained to recognize all 3,806 actions, i.e., verb-noun
> pairs in the dataset. We marginalize over verbs to obtain noun
> predictions and vice versa.

https://arxiv.org/pdf/2201.08377.pdf

Thank you in advanced for any help!

Comment: Welcome to [so]. This site is not a code-writing or tutoring service, it is best used when you have a specific problem with written code. Your question, reads like "Can someone code this for me" or "Show me a tutorial or information on how to code this" which are off-topic for Stackoverflow. Please take the [tour], read [what are you asking].

Comment: @itprorh66 Hi, I don't see the problem, I'm attaching the code I've done and my output. I'm asking if somebody knows why it's not correct as my output is not what it should be... I apologize if the question was not correctly formulated.

Comment: If you can't explain what is wrong with your code, why do you think we can?